# Generics in static factory methods? (Java)

Tags: java, static-methods, factory-pattern

I have an assignment that is requiring me to use the factory pattern for implementing an immutable data structure, but the problem is that the abstract class is generic, and having static methods make references to generic types is giving me problems.  My assignment is requiring me to use static methods so I'm starting to panic.  Any help/suggestions?
*EDIT* added some sample code, and here is the specification for one of the methods the professor gave us
Signature:

ExampleClass.method1 :  ExampleClass, T -> ExampleClass

ExampleClass.method2 :  ExampleClass - > T

```
public abstract class ExampleClass<T>{

   //static method creates a new subclass of Example ("Push" method)
   public static Class method1(T x, ExampleClass c){
       return new method1(x, f);
    }   

   //Supposed to return an object type T ("pop" method)
   public static T method2(ExampleClass c){
       return c.method2Dynamic();
   }
```

both of the methods I have like these are giving me problems in eclipse.

Comment: any code sample you can provide?

Comment: the question is very vague. You should write what you have come up with so far and then people will be able to correct, suggest improvements on that, thus answering your question. Because as it is, you're asking someone to write the assignment for you

Comment: added some example code for you.

Comment: What is your type T? You might want to use some real world example for that one. The problem you might have with this is that the class `ExampleClass` uses generics while your arguments don't provide any generic types (or rather they are declared as `ExampleClass<Object>`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you actually want to do, but let's suppose the problem is you are just looking for the right syntax:

```
public class ExampleClass<T> {
    public static <T> Class<T> method1(T x, ExampleClass<T> c) {
        return c.method3(x);
    }
    public static <T> T method2(ExampleClass<T> c) {
        return c.method2Dynamic();
    }
    private Class<T> method3(T x) {
        return null;
    }
    private T method2Dynamic() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) for help with generic methods (as opposed to generic classes).

From your description thus far, the static method vs. instance method question shouldn't come into play here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a generified class, you can't use the type parameters in static methods since they don't make sense there. For example, consider `ArrayList<T>`. You can create a `ArrayList<String> stingList = new ArrayList<String>()` and a `ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>`. So now you have to instances of ArrayList, each with their own parameter type, and instance methods that can take advantage of that parameter type like `get`. But static methods belong to the class not the instance, so when you call a static method you call it like `ArrayList.staticMethod()` NOT `stringList.staticMethod()` or `integerList.staticMethod()` (you can do that as well, but it doesn't really make sense, since the static method cannot access instance variables, so it does the exact same thing as calling it on the class). But when you call it on the class, the class is just ArrayList, without any type parameters, since the type parameters are only used by instances.

You can however have methods that have their own type parameter, which is independent of the type parameter of the class, like Thomas shows in his answer. So you can then call those method like `ExampleClass.<String> staticMethod()`; notice that ExampleClass has no type parameter here, but the method does have it. (you can omit the `<String>` in the method call if the compiler can infer it from the parameters used, or the return type: `String s = ExampleClass.method2(new ExampleSubclass<String>())`; it usually does a pretty good job at inferring it)